# Проверка доступности веб узла

Tags: android, java

Возможна ли проверка доступности веб узла средствами JAVA кроме InetAddress.isReachable()? 
InetAddress.isReachable() всегда возвращает false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю как это поможет/не поможет, но опишу мой простой ход мысли, в более конкретном случае для андроида. И так нам нужно подключится к какому-то серверу и получить от него ответ, конечно, сначала хочется проверить его доступность, сначала хочется написать метод, класс, поставить проверку для этого (с учетом того что ты нечего не пропустили, дал права в манифесте и тд), НО в этот момент нужно задать вопрос - ЗАЧЕМ ОНА? немного подумав оказывается она лишней, так как тебе не важно знать, есть ли подключения или нет(если это не банальная, конкретная задача проверить наличие подключения), тебе нужен ответ от сервера, получается проверка лишняя, так как запрос ты посылаешь и вариант 1 - все хорошо и ты получаешь ответ, 2 - ты получаешь ответ, что нету доступа, 3 - вылетаешь ошибка, что нету подключения, получается вариант 3 отбрасывает вопрос проверки.

Comment: Да, это логично, но было неприемлимо ждать так долго, сейчас воспользовался HttpParams  и сократил время до двух секунд.

Answer (score 2):

Никто не мешает реализовать ручками работу через сокеты. Просто подключаетесь к 80 порту и отправляете что то в стиле "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1nn" и ждете ответ.
Если ответ не приходит за приемлемое время - считает, что вебузел недоступен. Что считать приемлемым временем? все зависит от Вас. Может 1 секунда будет много, а может минута будет мало.

Если пишете утилиту мониторинга своего сервера, то можно обращаться к своей страничке. Но тогда уже наверно и использовать готовые классы для работы с http от org.apache.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот эту штуку [Java Network Commands](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javanetcomm/).

Answer (score 0):

например, так:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://url.com");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if(responseCode==200){ // url найден  
}
```